# How to upload file on Google cloud storage using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-api-nodejs-client

I am developing chat application REST API, and I want to upload all files (i.e. images, audio, video etc) on Google Cloud Storage.
I got the library files form the documentation of google cloud, and using it in POST method API.

Here is my code ref

https://medium.com/google-cloud/upload-images-to-google-cloud-storage-with-react-native-and-expressjs-61b8874abc49

It's not uploading the image to google cloud.

Comment: In order to get appropriate help you need to give us your code and tell us what is actually happening. You tell us "Its not uploading the image to google cloud." which is all well and good, but doesn't tell us what its actually doing. Read more on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As for how to upload files to Google Cloud Storage you can refer to the [client libraries documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-basics).

Comment: Hi Ritesh Doomra, are you still experiencing this issue? If you are, do you have an error message?

Thank you!